# How do I serve a firebase site using the domain from another firebase site?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase site with a domain of `gs-domain1.web.app`.
I have a second firebase site with a domain of `gs-domain1.web.app`.

Now, I want all traffic to go through the `gs-domain1.web.app`. However, when the path matches a specific route, like, `/users/:id/pages`, I want the site on `gs-domain2.web.app` to take over without switching the domain, but maintaining the path.

I believe a redirect will not work because it physically switches the domain.
I believe a rewrite will not work because I can't recreate the path on the destination.

Both the application on domain1 and domain2 are single-page applications (react and vue respectfully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firebase, you could host more than one site in one project and that would solve your problem.

Host/Deploy the react code to firebase and link the site with the URL of **gs-domain2.web.app**
and
do another hosting in the same project as the react but vue on **gs-domain2.web.app**

After you have successfully linked the domain and hosted the sites... Link the URL together with  or  anyone you like.

PROS: Your sites would load separately and would be faster.

Also,

It would be great if you put all the code under one domain

Then you can use different paths for the 2 sites so they would be easily identifiable.
so you have : **gs-domain1.web.app/path1** and **gs-domain1.web.app/path2**

***You will find the add another site function at the bottom of the hosting section below*** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5vJU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "take over without switching the domain, but maintaining the path". If you mean that you want the user to now see the page on `gs-domain1.web.app` when at this specific path, but still have `gs-domain1.web.app` as the domain in the url in their browser, I can only really think of two good ways to do this.

1. You use an iFrame to display the page from `gs-domain2.web.app` as the entire contents of the page on `gs-domain1.web.app` at the specific path. This can potentially introduce weirdness if the second page is complex.
2. You get rid of the second domain and instead move that codebase over to the first domain and write some middleware that serves from the first codebase whenever the user is requesting a path that should come from `gs-domain1.web.app` currently and serves from the second codebase whenever a user requests a path that should currently be coming from `gs-domain2.web.app`. I feel that this would be the more 'correct' approach if this is the desired behavior you want.

Alternatively, if you do not care what domain the user is seeing, I would suggest, as you mentioned, merely setting up some clever redirects to bounce users between the two based on which path they are requesting.

I hope this was helpful and goodluck!

Comment: As Timileyin said in their answer, 'combining' the codebases could be done by moving them both under the same project in Firebase whcich would allow them to share Firebase resources. You would then have to write the middleware I mentioned and expose that as the public website which could then direct traffic between the two.